# server side passport OAuth testing: passportStub install app testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am using code from this angular client-side auth project, which is a very good starter project: https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth

Right now I am trying to setup the integrated sever api testing. Since I am not using passport twitter/google etc, and am only using the local strategy, I commented out all the code for other oAuth stategies.

Now when I run the test, I get the following error:

`line: passportStub.install(app)`

> > Mocha exploded!
> >     TypeError: Cannot call method 'unshift' of undefined
> >
> > ```
> > at Object.exports.install (/Users/ge/projects/ProjectA/node_modules/passport-stub/lib.coffee:36:27)
> >
> > at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ge/projects/ProjectA/server/tests/integration/index.spec.js:5:14)
> >
> > at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
> >
> > at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
> > ```

but if I comment that line off, the test runs a few tests.

For the life of me I can't figure out what's going on, and what the app.stack object is.

Here is the head of the testing script:

```
var app = require('../../../server'),
    request = require('supertest'),
    passportStub = require('passport-stub');
passportStub.install(app);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea of *passport-stub* is to add a middleware to your express app that takes over the original passport module. *app.stack* is the stack of middleware your app has already registered. When you call *passportStub.install(app)*, we'll register a middleware in front of all others, that's why we call *unshift*.

Sharing a gist of how your server is setup can help troubleshooting it.
Looking at angular-client-side-auth, it seems to be exporting the express app correctly (https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth/blob/master/server.js#L7), but one thing that comes to my mind, by seeing the error and as you said you've commented out a few things, is that your *'../../../server'* is not correctly exporting the express app.

Let me know!

Comment: Thanks Guilherme! You answer beat my own debug by ten minutes! 

You diagnosis above is correct. The problem is solved by having adding a line to properly **export** the app in the `server.js` file.

The line is the following: I found this out by doing line-by-line comparison with @fnakstad original code:

**before**: `var app = express()` 
**after**: `var app = module.exports = express()`